# Bouncy Castle valid OID for Ed25519 key pair to generate X509Certificate

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, ed25519

I am using BouncyCastle library to generate x509Certificate, I am able to successfully generate RSA keypair based certificate but failing to generate using Ed25519 keypair based certificate.

It seems like the string value of signature algorithm `SHA256WithEd25519` is not a valid OID in BouncyCastle.

```
    public static X509Certificate GenerateCertificate(string subject, bool isNotRSA)
    {
        X509V3CertificateGenerator x509V3CertificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        X509Name x509Name = new X509Name(subject);
        BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());
        x509V3CertificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(bigInteger);
        x509V3CertificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(x509Name);
        x509V3CertificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(x509Name);
        x509V3CertificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(10));
        x509V3CertificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.UtcNow);

        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair asymmetricCipherKeyPair = null;
        string signatureAlgorithm = string.Empty;
        if (isNotRSA)
        {
            Ed25519KeyPairGenerator ed25519KeyPairGenerator = new Ed25519KeyPairGenerator();
            ed25519KeyPairGenerator.Init(new Ed25519KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom()));
            asymmetricCipherKeyPair = ed25519KeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
            signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256WithEd25519";
        }
        else
        {
            RsaKeyPairGenerator rsaKeyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
            rsaKeyPairGenerator.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), 2048));
            asymmetricCipherKeyPair = rsaKeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
            signatureAlgorithm = "SHA256WithRSA";
        }

        x509V3CertificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(asymmetricCipherKeyPair.Public);

        ISignatureFactory signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory(signatureAlgorithm, asymmetricCipherKeyPair.Private, new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()));

        X509Certificate x509Certificate = x509V3CertificateGenerator.Generate(signatureFactory);

        return x509Certificate;
    }
```

What is the valid OID for Ed25519 key pair in BouncyCastle library?

Answer (score 0):

The signature algorithm should be "Ed25519".

[BouncyCastle test code provides excellent pointers](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/test/EdECTest.java)